# Main php.ini file for phpmyadmin in Centos 6.4 with ISP Config 3

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, centos

Hi I'm trying to upload a backup database via phpmyadmin. But the max upload size is 2mb.

I changed php.ini file and restarted the apache but it does not work. the ini file that I changed is in /etc/php.ini this does not seem to change anything.

I used this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.4-x86_64-apache2-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p3) to configure everything.

i tried following commands but there is nothing working.

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini

Can you help me how can I change this default server. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with changing file upload size like this in your php.ini

> post_max_size = 8M
>
> upload_max_filesize = 2M

to

> post_max_size = 100M
>
> upload_max_filesize = 100M

Comment: you don't understand the question. The problem is these changes does not apply. they don't work!

Answer (score 0):

In in your php.ini file these two configuration need to be changed

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

Common pitfalls from manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php